# Imagem destacada do Wordpress não aparece no Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnail

Configurei no meu functions.php o código que habilita as Post Thumbnails do tema, mas não aparece no wp-admin.

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 1280, 720 );
```

Quando crio um post, não aparece a opção para fazer upload da imagem destacada. Então, fiz os seguintes procedimentos para tentar entender o que está acontecendo.

1. Desativei todos os plugins
2. Mudei de tema (e a imagem destacada aparece)
3. Removi todo o código do functions, deixando apenas o código acima
4. Atualizei o WordPress

Eu já não sei o que fazer, pesquisei bastante e não encontro solução. Alguém poderia ter piedade desta alma? Obrigado!!!

Comment: Problema sobrenatural.

Answer (score -1):

Você usou o hook `after_setup_theme` para adicionar o suporte aos thumbnails?

```
function theme_setup(){

    /** post thumbnail **/
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
```